# Unable to use YUM. RHEL 8.2 server hosted in Azure

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, curl, rhel8

I have a Red Hat server hosted in Azure and when I try to use yum to install software or do a system update I get the below error,

Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhui-rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rhui-rpms':

- Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/x86_64/baseos/os/repodata/repomd.xml [Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds]

The system has been registered in subscription manager.

Comment: Do you have egress firewall rules defined?

Comment: The VM can only access RHUI with Azure assigned public IP address, so make sure the traffic from VM is sent to Internet without any intermediates, such as proxy, VPN gateway and so on. These intermediates may alter the source IP address of packets from VM.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
yum clean all
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb